# PHP regular expression start and end with given number

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this `202009170439051466017152d0bd457094b54f32eb029c4e9111725`  I need to select the `1466017152` from that. (start with `146` and `ending on 10 char`)

Can anyone help me out from this?

Comment: it's not end with 10. i mean the lenght will be 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find the first index of `146` and get substring using [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function starting from that index to total length of `10` chars.

```
$a ="202009170439051466017152d0bd457094b54f32eb029c4e9111725";

echo substr($a, strpos($a,"146"), 10);

Output:
1466017152
```

Comment: Likely the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Regex is simple. Start with `146` and then select 7 chars ([example](https://regex101.com/r/e3zAKp/1)):

```regex
/(146.{7})/
```

---

So in PHP it would look like [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3cd5abda4bbc170f4b28911c7b7f5dc1467f317):

```php
$string = '202009170439051466017152d0bd457094b54f32eb029c4e9111725';
$pattern = '/(?<result>146.{7})/';

$results = null;

preg_match($pattern, $string, $results);

var_dump($results['result']);
// string(10) "1466017152"
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the question. But here it is the function to get the required substring from a string starting with a substring and end with the given length of character.

```
function get_string($string, $startWithStr, $len=10){
    $start = strpos($string, $startWithStr);
    return substr($string, $start, $len);
}

$fullstring = "202009170439051466017152d0bd457094b54f32eb029c4e9111725";
$requiredStr = get_string($fullstring, '146');
var_dump($requiredStr);
```